# What is the purpose of creating new node groups in aws eks instead of creating a new cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks

I wonder what is the reason of creating new node groups instead of creating a new eks cluster.
In which way multiple node groups in one cluster are isolated from each other? How are they connected?

Comment: Some use it for ML vs Non ML workloads in the same clusters.